# Parsing a problematic RSS feed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, rss

I have a small test app that parses a few RSS feeds. 
It all goes well for all except for one.

I scanned through the feed's XML and noticed that it fails once it reached a tag that has "&" in it. So, if I have a tag like this:

```
<like>beer & barbeque</like>
```

The log says that it found a string

```
beer
```

And it crashes with the exception

```
Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=68 "Operation could not be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 68.)
```

The most annoying thing is that I don't even need the data from the problematic tag.
Any idea how I can work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the feed is already failing... do a string replace on '`&<space>` ' to '`&amp;`' while you fight it out with the feed publisher to clean up his act.

The feed must be valid XML. Period.

Comment: That's what I first thought of, but this is what I got...
Bare in mind that the feed is not in English and has a whole bunch of non-ASCII characters.

I tried to convert the data to string using UTF8 -> got NULL
I tried to convert the data to string using ASCII -> got a string which when converted back to data (no changes) is impossible to parse.

I tried to init the string directly with the URL -> got a string  filled with junk.

The xml header claims that it's using ISO-8859-1 encoding, but as far as I know it's overridden by HTTP to UTF8.

Comment: The feed must be valid XML. Period. I'm with you 100%, I'm just trying to be nice... for now :)

Comment: Post the URL here if it's a public feed - and we'll have a look at it.

Comment: Can't do that, I'm afraid... Never mind, I persuaded the publisher to fix the feed. Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: Thats ok, sounds like you ended up with the best solution after all - getting the publisher to fix his feed. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

[Hpple](http://github.com/topfunky/hpple) is supposed to be able to parse "messy" HTML. Maybe it can handle your messy RSS.